# Can we mention groups (SP or AD) in SharePoint online site pages comments Section? If Yes, how?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-site

I want to mention a group in SharePoint comments. That group can be either SP Group or AD Group. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online does not support mentioning group in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, currently SharePoint only supports mentioning **M365/O365 groups** and not SharePoint groups.